# Modify a python package, remove it and re-install it: why modifications are persistent?

Tags: python, package

I am working in Windows.

- installed a python package with **conda** (Zipline, from the channel 'Quantopian'), in an environment:

> `conda install -c Quantopian zipline`

- modified code inside some .py files in the package. These .py file are in the package folder inside the environment folder.
- removed the package:

> `conda remove zipline`

- checked the package folder is not there anymore.
- reinstalled the package:

> `conda install -c Quantopian zipline`

- checked the .py files inside the package folders: the still retain the modifications I did.
  Why?

Comment: Could be side-effects from the `zipline` package dependencies not getting removed. Use `conda info zipline` to list dependencies

Comment: Should I remove the dependencies one by one? Or there is a quicker way?

Comment: That will be the way to go except it may break your environment as other key packages may depend on these dependencies(dependency hell). I'll recommend you install the package in a new environment